# Apache rewrite of subdomain based on environment

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to come up with a rewrite rule that will work in conf files for all the environments I support (qa, stage, dev, etc), so a common rewrite condition and rule to "rule" them all.

Example:

- subdomain.environment.site.com should redirect to environment.site.com
- *except* subdomain.site.com should redirect to www.site.com.
- It also shouldn't forward when some of the request URIs have stuff in them.

This is as far as I've come:

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   subdomain.$ENV.site.com [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/images
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/blah
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/blah-foo
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/foo-bar
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)         http://$ENV.site.com/$1 [L,R=302]
```

Obvious the $ENV isn't going to work, but I am having a having a helluva time trying to find a proper regex to make this work in all environments.

Comment: All could be replaced by a single one: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(images|blah|foo) [NC]`

Answer (score 0):

A little more research, hand banging and beer got me the solution.

It might not be pretty but it works. Answering so if anyone ever tries to do this, they have some sort of start here.

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^(sub)(\.)((?:[a-z][a-z]+))(\.)(site)(\.)(com) [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/image
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/blah
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/foobar
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/barfoo
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)         http://%3.%5.%7/$1 [L,R=302]
```